# Object declared as parent class calling subclass method

Tags: inheritance, overriding, vb.net-2010

Can someone explain this behaivour? I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` inherits `Foo` and overrides its `GetVar` function:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public myVar1 As Integer

    Public Overridable Function GetVar() As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.GetVar!()")
        Return myVar1
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Inherits Foo

    Public myVar2 As Integer

    Public Overrides Function GetVar() As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Bar.GetVar!()")
        Return MyBase.GetVar() + myVar2
    End Function

End Class
```

In my `main()` module, the following happens:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myBar As New Bar
    myBar.myVar1 = 2
    myBar.myVar2 = 2

    Dim myFoo As Foo
    myFoo = myBar

    Console.WriteLine(myFoo.GetVar())

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

And the output is:

```
Bar.GetVar()!
Foo.GetVar()!
4
```

Which seems odd to me - `myFoo` is declared as an object of type `Foo`, so I had thought that calling `myFoo.GetVar()` would call `Foo`'s implementation of `GetVar()` (outputting 2) - without explicitly downcasting it, I thought that the fact that `myFoo` is actually a `Bar` would be 'invisible' due to its `Foo` declaration. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `myFoo.getVar()` calls `getVar()` on the object that `myFoo` is pointing at. Whilst it doesn't *know* that said object is a `Bar` (and wouldn't be able to access things exclusive to `Bar`, like `myVar2`), it's still a `Bar` that's in there, which fires its own `getVar()` function.

I'm sure there's a name for this behaivour, but I can't remember it. Any takers?